# C++ Ambiguity issue

Tags: c++, inheritance, ambiguous

Let the following classes :

```
class BaseClass
{
    class OnSomeEventListener
    {
    public:
        enum SomeEnum { BLABLA }
        virtual void OnSomeEvent( SomeEnum eventData ) = 0;
    }
};

class ChildClass :
    public BaseClass,
    public BaseClass::OnSomeEventListener
{
    virtual void OnSomeEvent( BaseClass::OnSomeEventListener::SomeEnum eventData );
}
```

My question is : why do I need to specify `BaseClass::` in front of `OnSomeEventListener::SomeEnum eventData` in the method `virtual void OnSomeEvent( BaseClass::OnSomeEventListener::SomeEnum eventData );` ?

If I don't do it, it says that `OnSomeEventListener` is ambiguous between `BaseClass::OnSomeEventListener` and `BaseClass::OnSomeEventListener::OnSomeEventListener`

Why would it think i'm referencing the constructor instead of the `OnSomeEventListener` type ? Why would i need to prefix the argument type with `BaseClass::` since I'm already inside `BaseClass` ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why would i need to prefix the argument type with BaseClass:: since I'm already inside BaseClass ?

You are inside `BaseClass`, but you are *also* inside `OnSomeEventListener` because you inherit from both.

When the compiler parses a name, it doesn't think *"I need a type here, can this be an enum?"*, instead it thinks *"I have a name here, what can it be?"*. And in your case it can be two different things, depending on which base class is searched for the name.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the `BaseClass::OnSomeEventListener` scope at all since you bring that in with your inheritance of `BaseClass::OnSomeEventListener`:

```
class ChildClass:
  public BaseClass,
  public BaseClass::OnSomeEventListener
{
  virtual void OnSomeEvent(SomeEnum eventData);
};
```

That being said `OnSomeEventListener` in the `ChildClass` is ambiguous since it can be either the constructor or the class from that scope since you inherit both.

When trying to use the name `OnSomeEventListener::SomeEnum`, it wasn't preceded with `::` so the compiler uses the [unqualified lookup rules](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup) to create a *lookup set*. And from the compiler error you can see it first only considers `OnSomeEventListener` which directly becomes ambiguous in that scope since both the class itself and the constructor matches.

Comment: Thank for your answer. But how come the compiler considers the possibility that we are referencing a constructor inside the definition of the parameters ?

Comment: I updated the answer with some more details. But the lookup rules contain a lot of intricacies and *gotchas* that I'm not that familiar with.